# Rebuilding a DAG if all of a node's descendants and ancestors are known as a flat list

Tags: graph-theory

I have problem that's quite different to many questions about DAGs and am thus having a hard time finding answers. That may mean that it's just very simple.

Background: I have to build the Terraform DAG in Python by parsing the statefile. The graph is known to be acyclic and all nodes are connected to a single root in my implementation. All nodes store the *full* list of their ancestors as a flat list.

So the question is not about the specific programming implementation but about the algorithm I would need to use for this. I've been using different sample graphs for myself and can't say for sure that they cover all potential problems but I've found some that stumped me even there.

They essentially all boil down to deciding whether there is something directly between two nodes.

Example.

```
                      Forward ("deps of")       Reverse ("depends on")
g --> a <-------.     a = []                    a = [bcdefghi]
^     ^^        |     b = [aefi]                b = [c]
|     |  \      |     c = [abdfi]               c = []
h     |   \     |     d = [afi]                 d = [c]
      b-> e     |     e = [afi]                 e = [b]
      ^   |     |     f = [ai]                  f = [bcde]
      |   v     |     g = [a]                   g = [h]
      c   f --> i     h = [ag]                  h = []
      |   ^           i = [a]                   i = [bcdef]
      v   |
      d---'
```

Given only the two columns on the right, how can I derive the DAG on the left? Is there maybe a standard algorithm for this that I'm unaware of?

(I sincerely hope I didn't make any confusing mistakes in the graph or lists but I've staring at these things for way too long by now.)

Comment: Duplicate question on https://cs.stackexchange.com: [Reconstruct directed graph from list of ancestors for each node](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/reconstruct-directed-graph-from-list-of-ancestors-for-each-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you could add an edge from `h` to `a`. It would change the graph (while keeping it a DAG), but it would not change either of those columns.

The task is impossible.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what happens when you keep working at such things for too long. You are of course correct - thank you! And such a simple answer. Then I wonder how Terraform does it - it _can_ create an actual drawn graph from just the statefile so there must be some auxiliary information in there that I missed - or maybe I simply misinterpreted how it works.

Comment: After recreating this graph with null_resources and looking at it with the above background, I simply seem to have misunderstood how Terraform uses its tfstate and tfplan. It does only contain the information I listed so the dependency information in these files must not be used for resolution at all. Wouldn't have known without this being highlighted, so thanks again!

Comment: Although there are multiple DAGs that would lead to the same lists of ancestors, you can still use your list of ancestors to construct a DAG that would give that list. For instance, add an arc u->v iff u is listed as an ancestor of v. The resulting DAG is the "transitive closure" of any DAG that gives the same list of ancestors. Alternatively, you could look for a "minimal" DAG, a DAG that gives the same list of ancestors but with as few arcs as possible.

Comment: @Stef, that's probably very helpful in other cases where people have this problem but unfortunately in this case, it's not a possible approach since it's a dependency graph. If the dependencies are optimized away or somehow modified, they won't represent the real-world state any more.